# Local port forwarding and Putty connection

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding, putty

I have 2 ssh-servers on virtual machines. **Debian** (192.168.141.129) and **Kali** Linux (192.168.141.136). On Debian I [forwarded local port 22 to Kali port 2027](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q23uw.png), so on Kali when connecting to local port 2027 I am [redirected to ssh-server on Debian](https://i.stack.imgur.com/25nlM.png).

Now I need to use Putty on the third virtual machine (192.168.141.132) to connect to Kali and then to be redirected to Debian ssh server. I can do it manually by connecting from Putty to Kali and then repeating the second screenshot. But it woild be better to do it automaticaly. For that i somehow should to connect from Putty to kali's local port 2027. SSH-session on Putty works only with port 22 and ssh-server on Kali refuses to forward port 2027 to port 22 or 2222.

Is there actually any way to bind these local ports on Kali or connect directly to port 2027 from Putty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, just directly connect to your kali VM on port 2027 in Putty. You also may have to enable `GatewayPorts yes` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` as this is disabled by default and will make forwarded ports only listen on the `localhost`.

Comment: Oh thank you. I also needed to define the user on Kali I wanted to connect to, otherwise Putty refused to connect to 2027.